# Can I connect MSAccess to a SQL Server rather than to a specific SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I want to create linked tables in MSAccess that connect to tables in a number of different databases on the same SQL Server. Do I have to create a distinct ODBC datasource for each database? It looks like I do - at Step 9 in https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/microsoft_access_2016/howto/how_to_link_an_access_database_to_sql_server_in_microsoft_access_2016.cfm
I have to choose a DB. There seems to be no way to go "up a level" and "back down a level" with an ODBC connection, as I might do in a query on SQL Server e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM SM_SIS..tblStudents JOIN tblCourses
```

here, tblCourses is in the current DB, tblStudents is in a different DB called SM_SIS.

Is there another type of connection I can use to create linked tables, which connects to a SQL Server rather than a specific database on a SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is always in one specific database. A linked table will always be in one database.

You can link to multiple tables in different databases or even different servers in Access, and use them in one query. You will have to execute them through Access, though.

If you're looking to query a server directly, use a pass-through query, and construct the query string manually. Your tutorial uses the ODBC data source manager for everything, something I certainly don't recommend. If you manually create an ODBC connection string, you can choose to specify a database or not to specify one.

Comment: This response is tantalising, but I fear ultimately not a solution. Doesn't a pass-thru query also require an ODBC DSN, and it doesn't make any difference whether it is created manually or via the interface provided? My understanding is that a DSN is just a set of values in the Registry at the end of the day, and creating them "manually" doesn't extend their scope. I have just tried creating an ODBC DSN and not specified the database (admittedly via the interface) , but in that case the "master" database is selected. So I think the question remains unanswered (or at least, an implicit "No").

Comment: Since a pass-through query executes it's SQL directly on SQL server, anything that's valid there will pass. You can execute your query using a pass-through query. Even on SQL server using SSMS, you're always executing in a database. Every query is handled by a database. The answer isn't _no_, it's _your question is wrong and thus can't really be answered_.

Comment: The question is legitimate and using a pass-through query is exactly what is needed, using these instructions https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access

Comment: A shame we didn't understand one another

Comment: Eh... I precisely told you _If you're looking to query a server directly, use a pass-through query_. Your question _to create linked tables, which connects to a SQL Server rather than a specific database on a SQL Server_ was impossible, since tables are always in a database.